# Strange browser issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a strange browser issue regarding my windows forms app.
I have placed a web browser in my form and I'm simply trying to load google.

The problem is that the browser is auto refreshing it every few seconds and it makes it useless.

I have used:

```
webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://google.com");
```

and

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");
```

And the result is the same. The page is still auto refreshing. It's the first time I'm facing this issue. Is there anyone who faced it and can help me?

I'm running the code on Visual Studio 2012 - windows 7 x64

**EDIT:**

Here is the code of the form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint at the navigate line to see if you're ending up there more than once?

Comment: yes the command is executed more than once, but I can not understand why and how I can avoid it. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see how you're wiring things up, but to me it looks like you're wiring [WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) to navigate to Google. The problem is;

> The WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted event *occurs when the WebBrowser control finishes loading a document*.

In other words, every time you get an event that the page has finished loading, you're calling `webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");` which reloads it again.

Comment: I see, but I'm a beginner and I have no idea on how to change it. I just got the web browser from the tool box and dragged it into my form. How I am supposed to change it rite now?

Comment: @tsvetanakos Go to the forms designer and set the `Url` property to `http://www.google.com` instead. That will make the control load google when it starts. Then click the little "flash" button to go to the events, and remove the value in "DocumentCompleted", that will stop it from running code when the page has loaded. When that's done, you can remove the entire `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` method.

Comment: Ok, but what can I doo when I will need to change the URL programaticaly. I mean that I won't show only google's web page there.

Comment: @tsvetanakos Where you want to change it, just call `webBrowser1.Navigate(url);` just like you do now. Just don't do it in DocumentCompleted or it'll keep reloading :)